# Find the image of set under the mapping

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $D = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | 1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 2, -x \le y \le x \}$ and let $(u, v) = F(x, y) = (x^2 + y^2, 2xy)$. Find the image of $D$ under the mapping $F$

Can someone give me some ideas?

So the region is between the circle of radius $1$ and $2$, but with restriction $y \le |x|$. How do I fit this in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The condition $-x\leqslant y\leqslant x$ is valid only when $x\geqslant0$. Asserting that $-x\leqslant y\leqslant x$ means then that if you express $(x,y)$ in polar coordinates ($x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$), then $-\frac\pi4\leqslant\theta\leqslant\frac\pi4$.

If $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, then$$F(x,y)=F(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\bigl(r^2,r^2\sin(2\theta)\bigr)=r^2\bigl(1,\sin(2\theta)\bigr).$$Since, for the points of $D$, $r\in\bigl[1,\sqrt2\bigr]$ and $\theta\in\bigl[-\frac\pi4,\frac\pi4\bigr]$, the image of $D$ by $F$ is the set of those points of the form $R(1,\sin\alpha)$ with $R\in[1,2]$ and $\alpha\in\bigl[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\bigr]$. This is a trapezium, whose vertices are $(1,\pm1)$ and $(2,\pm2))$.

Comment: Shouldnt it be $r \in [1, \sqrt{2}]$, since the restriction was $1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 2 \implies 1 \le r^2 \le 2$?

Comment: @Bana Right! I will edit my answer.